# PHP customizing variables in the scope dynamically

Tags: php, templates, dynamic, scope, include

I'm creating an application in php where I have a function which will include php template files. For the sake of usability I would like to dynamically define which variables will be available in the included files scope. For example:

```
includeTemplate( 'myinclude.php', array(
    'var1' => 'key1',
    'var2' => 'key2',
) );

function includeTemplate( $path, $variables ) {
    include( $path );
}
```

And in myinclude.php

```
echo $var1; // key1
echo $var2; // key2
```

Is this possible? And if not are there any other suggestions for how to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are passed as an array of key/value pairs.... to use them by name/key, you'll have to [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) them from the array as individual named variables

```
extract($variables);
```

Though this isn't a very clean approach to what you're trying to do

Comment: He want do dynamically include files. (Given a string try to include that string as file from the same folder)

Comment: @MarcoMura - he also wants to use the variables from the `$variables` array as variables (e.g. `echo $var1;`) from within his template; extracting before the include allows that

Comment: If they are included in the function call then he can see them as $variables array then =)

Comment: But his template doesn't contain a single reference to `$variables`, only to `$var1` and `$var2`

Answer (score 0):

The answer i've fount it's old but to make it works you may need to do this:

```
includeTemplate( 'myinclude.php', array(
    'var1' => 'key1',
    'var2' => 'key2',
) );

function includeTemplate( $path, $variables ) {
    include("$path");
}
```

include($path) needs " to parse the var, then giving it's content to the Include function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including files for your templates why not take a look at [object oriented php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)? Using [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) you could create a class for a 'base' template and then have classes for other templates that extend your original.

```
class baseTemplate 
{
    public $var1 = value; 
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

class subTemplate extends baseTemplate
{
    public $var2 = value; 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Variables will be linked only to their corresponding classes and parents.

```
//contains $var1
$template1 = new baseTemplate();
echo $template1->var1;

//contains $var1 & $var2
$template2 = new subTemplate();
echo $template2->var1 . " " . $template2->var2;
```

Obviously you'll have to learn a bit about object oriented programming if you're not familiar with this but it might be the better approach.

Comment: Funny, the reason I asked this question was actually to preserve my applications oop programming style. The include is an html file similar to how wordpress has it's template php files. However, whereas wordpress operates with functions like so foo_bar, I want functions like this $foo->bar. My problem is how to include $foo automagically in the file.

Comment: PHP actually has a function called autoload which you can use to automatically include the class files. This way you only have to include your autoload function. Here's a link if you want to read about it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php